# How can I check in itemadded event whether itemupdated event will fire after or not?

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2013

I need to skip my code in itemadded event if itemupdated event will fire after it. Is there any common solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

Just remove itemadded then. Itempupdated is always triggered even when the item is just created. So I don't see why you need ItemAdded.

- If you create an item --> ItemAdded --> ItemUpdated
- If you update an item --> ItemUpdated

Comment: itemupdated event is not firing every time after itemadded. It is firing only when Require Check Out option is enabled. https://www.simple-talk.com/dotnet/.net-tools/managing-itemupdating-and-itemupdated-events-firing-twice-in-a-sharepoint-item-event-receiver/

Comment: also when we change file metadata or content after adding to the library. It may be right after when we was added file to library.

Comment: I could not find how to skip itemadded event but I found how to check if itemupdate event was fired write after itemadded event so I can undo my changes in itemupdate. There is the SPItemEventProperties.Versionless property which can do the trick. Here is the source http://sharepointbulletin.blogspot.com/2013/08/preventing-multiple-events-from.html